# Xcode : How to view debug navigator memory report after UI test execute

Tags: xcode

I want to autorun UI test and see the memory report in the debug navigator, but the report disappears after the debug run. Is there a way to show it later?

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctmemorymetric ?

Comment: matt, thanks for reply. No. It's memory report https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/gathering-information-about-memory-use

Comment: You have already said that that does not persist its memory report. I'm telling you a tool that _does_ persist its memory report. The best way probably is to exercise the app with Instruments recording the allocations.

Comment: matt, Thanks to your input, I was able to solve the problem using Instruments recording the allocations. Thanks so much!